# Amazon Alexa get value of slot

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit, slot

I want to store what a user is saying (or get the value of a slot) and store it in a variable. Something like this:

```
String employee = intent.getSlot("Employee").getValue();
```

Alexa gives the right speechOutput so it gets the slot, however if i Say "Peter" and then make an `if-statement (employee == "Peter")` it always seems to be false. Can someone explain what I am missing?

```
public static SpeechletResponse getFact(final Intent intent, final Session session) {


    Map<String, Slot> slots = intent.getSlots();

    // Get the employee from the list of slots.
    Slot employeeSlot = slots.get("Employee");
    String speechText, repromptText;

    if (employeeSlot != null) {
        String employee = employeeSlot.getValue();

        if (employee == "Peter") {
            speechText =
                    String.format("Pasta is the favorite food of %s.", mitarbeiter);
        } else {
            // I always end up here
        }
```

...

Comment: use .equals when you compare Strings

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think of that.